# Cannot assign string to property Id in Repository

Tags: symfony

I try to integrate my pure PHP project into Symfony.

My Entity without setters. Only __constructor and getters:

```
final class Company
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=36, unique=true)
     */
    private Id $id;
...
```

My `Id` value-object:

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

final class Id
{
    private $id;

    public function __construct(string $id)
    {

        $this->id = $id;
    }
```

When I try to use repository to find entities

```
    public function findByExampleField($value): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->andWhere('c.name LIKE :val')          
            ->orWhere('c.address.region LIKE :val')
            ->orWhere('c.address.city LIKE :val')
            ->orWhere('c.address.street LIKE :val')
            ->setParameter('val', '%'.$value.'%')
            ->orderBy('c.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

I get an error
 `[TypeError] Cannot assign string to property App\Company\Domain\Entity\Company::$id of type App\Company\Domain\VO\Id`

Should I use my own custom hydrator or how can I figure it out?

Comment: The problem is that @ORM\Column(type="string") says the field is a string but private Id $id; means it is a relationship to an entity of type App\Company\Domain\VO\Id. Why don't you use an autogenerated id with @ORM\GeneratedValue()?

Comment: If you want to have a separate entity for the id you could use embeddable https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/tutorials/embeddables.html#separating-concerns-using-embeddables

Comment: Thanks. I use Ramsey/UUID to generate uuid in handler. So I need `string` to save it in database.

Comment: I use embedded for Address. Thanks, I'll try to do it with ID (if doctrine allows to do it (without primary key)

Comment: Might be worth while to read through [Symfony 5.2 UUID Doctrine types](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-doctrine-types-for-uuid-and-ulid).  Just to get a different perspective on uuid's and Doctrine.  I get that you want to use a value object but Doctrine is just not very good with them.  Support for embedded objects is limited at best.  It might be possible for you to add your own Doctrine type which would allow you to do things like type="MyId". Not sure if it is worth the effort or not.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with a CustomIdGenerator. The following is from an implementation I built in Symfony 4.4 (simplified for brevity).

In my entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="CUSTOM")
 * @ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class="App\Generator\AppIdGenerator")
 */
private $id;
```

Then in `App\Generator\AppIdGenerator`:

```
namespace App\Generator;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidOrderedTimeGenerator;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

class AppIdGenerator extends UuidOrderedTimeGenerator
{
  /**
   * Generate an identifier
   *
   * @param \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager  $em
   * @param \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity $entity
   *
   * @return string
   * @throws \Exception
   */
  public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
  {
    // your custom identifier logic here
    $uuid = Uuid::uuid1(); // object 

    return $uuid->toString(); // return the string representation
  }
}
```

This is portable and you can use it on any/all your entities by annotating the `Entity::id`.